# Mongoose Schema validate XOR fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema

```
var Mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = Mongoose.Schema;

var headerSchema = new Schema({
    lang : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        match: [ /^(en|es|pt)$/, "{VALUE} is not a supported language" ],
        index: { unique: true }
    },
    menu : {
        type: [{
            link: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Link"},
            dropdown: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Dropdown"},
            autopopulate: true
        }]
    }
});

headerSchema.plugin(require("mongoose-autopopulate"));

module.exports = Mongoose.model("header", headerSchema);
```

As you might have guessed, this describes a config document for the header of a webpage. This header has a nav (menu in the schema) where each item can be either a dropdown or a link, but not both. Is there a way to add custom validation to my schema to only allow saving the document if either of those is set, but not both and not neither? (think of the boolean operation XOR)

For example, this is a valid header document:

```
{
  lang: "es",
  menu: [{
    link: {
      title: "Contact",
      href: "/contact"
    }
  }, {
    dropdown: {
     title: "FAQ",
     links: [{
       title: "What is this?",
       href : "/about"
     }]
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

```
menu : {
    type: [{
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        required: true,
        validate: [ isDropdownOrLink, "{VALUE} is neither a dropdown nor a link" ]
    }]
}

function isDropdownOrLink (value) {
    if (!value) {
        return false;
    }

    return value instanceof Link || value instanceof Dropdown;
}
```

Also using Schema.Types.Mixed simplified my schema. I'm leaving the question open for now though, since my answer changes the original question a little bit (since I've changed the schema)